# Designing Database For Comic Reading Website

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently designing a database for a comic reading website for my study case. I've been wondering what the proper way of designing it when a comic has many chapters and each chapter stores multiple image content. I'm thinking of two possible solutions:

Example Case : Adding Chapter 1 That Contain 10 Images
[image: Design 1]

1. with this design i will have to add 10 new row in **Content Table**

[image: Design 2]

2. with this design i just need to add a new row in with 10 value (image_path1 to image_path10) in **Content Table**

with this comparison, **No 2** is more effective but in my case a chapter will not always contains 10 images it will be less or more and that will make some column left unused.

my question is : which design should i use or is there proper way to design this database ?

Comment: No1 is correctly normalised, no2 is not, and will be harder to run various queries on later, and more tiresome/repetitive to write UI code for too. Also it's less flexible, as you've already noticed yourself. In constrast, only having to insert 1 row instead of 10 doesn't actually give any particular advantages. No1 is the better choice.

Comment: what if a comic have 500 chapter with total 2000+ images on it, on that case we will need to add about 2000+ new row on Content Table. will it  cause problem ?

Comment: Why would it cause a problem, do you expect? In terms of a database, that is a trivial, insignificant number of rows. Maybe when you get to several million rows you might need to start having a conversation about performance, but even then if your hardware is adequate and your database is properly indexed it shouldn't cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

No1 is correctly normalised, no2 is not, and will be harder to run various queries on later, and more tiresome/repetitive to write UI code for too. Also it's less flexible, as you've already noticed yourself.

In constrast, only having to insert 1 row instead of 10 doesn't actually give any particular advantages.

No1 is the better choice.